# Javascript + ActionScript: How to convert bytearray returned from Actionscript to image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have bytearray returned from ActionScript to Javascript through ExternalInterface call. Now, i have to convert this byteaarray to image in Javascript code. pls help...with any sample code...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: OR any other alternative also fine...I can save using AS3 itself but i do not want SAVE dialog to appear...

Comment: you won't be able to save it without user interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to this problem, neither of which I have tested so try them out:

### HTML5 Canvas

First, using ActionScript convert your byte array to integer array. You will need four values for:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Alpha

Transfer this to Javascript, either using string representation or plain numbers and then load these numbers into the canvas:

```
var canvasData = ; // data from actionscript
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var imgData=ctx.createImageData(100,100);
for (var i=0;i<imgData.width*imgData.height*4;i+=4)
{
  imgData.data[i+0]=canvasData[i][0]; // red
  imgData.data[i+1]=canvasData[i][1]; // green
  imgData.data[i+2]=canvasData[i][2]; // blue
  imgData.data[i+3]=canvasData[i][3]; // alpha
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData,10,10);
```

### Base64-encoded through CSS

If you don't want to rely on HTML5, use ActionScript to convert the byte array to a base64 string and then insert the image using the following css rule:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,__base64_data__);
```

and replace `__base64_data__` with the generated string. This could be done dynamically using JQuery:

```
$('#img').css("background-image", "url(data:image/png;base64,__base64_data__)");
```

This also seems to be a much more efficient method than HTML5 Canvas, although actual performance will depend on the image size.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in an `ArrayBuffer` and inject this into a `canvas` to display as explained here :
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/